# Pagination links do not work after first page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to fix this pagination script. It seems when I click on the pagination links, [1], [2], [3], [4] or [5], it doesn't work. It just shows the first page and when clicking on the next numbers nothing happens.

**The main page looks like this (pagination.php):**

```
<?php
    include_once('generate_pagination.php');
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_pagination.js"></script>

<div id="loading" ></div>
<div id="content" data-page="1"></div>

<ul id="pagination">
    <?php generate_pagination() ?>
</ul>

<br/>
<br/>

<a href="#" class="category" id="marketing">Marketing</a>
<a href="#" class="category" id="automotive">Automotive</a>
<a href="#" class="category" id="sports">Sports</a>
```

**Then, generate_pagination.php:**

```
<?php
    function generate_pagination($sql) {
        include_once('config.php');
        $per_page = 3;

        //Calculating no of pages
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $pages = ceil($count[0]/$per_page);

        //Pagination numbers
        for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
        {
            echo '<li class="page_numbers" id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
        }
    }
    $ids = $_GET['ids'];
    generate_pagination("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM explore WHERE category='$ids'");
?>
```

Where is the problem occurring and how do I rid of the problem?

Comment: "Hey, dubug this bunch of code for me!"  question

Comment: @ Col, I'm still learning these languages and after a lot of time spent looking through the entire script and not finding a solution, I thought I might ask for some assistance from a more experienced programmer. I in no way intended to just throw a bunch of code in peoples faces. I'd appreciate it if you left your 'smart' comments somewhere else.

Comment: In the future, you should elaborate in detail what exactly happens and what exactly happens not. E.g. which lines of code were actually executed and which unexpectedly not. Which variables were actually set and which unexpectedly not. Which variables were actually passed around and which unexpectedly not. Etcetera. 

In other words: just debug. To start, put some `echo` statements and/or `alert()` calls at strategic locations printing the variables of interest so that you can track that all down by just looking at the HTML page or the JS alert boxes.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, programming science has a more powerful technique to find and eliminate errors in the code, instead of "looking in the script to see something".

This technique called "debugging".

IBM has nice introduction article in this art, *[Debugging techniques for PHP programmers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/)*.

To debug an Ajax application is quite hard, but it's still possible. Divide your task into smaller ones and debug them separately. Feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that you're calling `generate_pagination` without the `$sql` parameter.

But I think we'd need to see what JavaScript code is being used in order to understand exactly what is wrong with the code. Where are the events defined for when you click on a page number?